# select every 3rd participate from a list and make and average in matlab

Tags: matlab

I got 3 lists with grades ranging from 0-100 represting 3 different tests.
each list has an equal number of indxes (represting participates).

For example- the 1st indexes in the lists- list1,list2 and list3, are the grades of the first particiapte in the 3 different tests.

I need to make a new group (named group1) that select evey 3rd participate, starting from the first, and than calculate the avarage of this group scores.

i'll appriciate any help!!

Comment: post some demo input data and your desired output as well as any code you have tried so far

Comment: i made a new score matrix named "scores_table":
scores_table = [test1_scores , test2_scores , test3_scores]; 

than calculated the mean of each student:
students_scores = mean(scores_table,2);

the new array i made- "students_scores",  is a list with the avarage of each student.
now i'd like to take every 3rd participate, starting from the 1st, and getting them into a new array, to be honest, i didn't find a way how to do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully instead of three 'lists' you are actually using a 3 column matrix for this? e.g.

```
testScores = [20 48 13; 
              85 90 93; 
              54 50 56; 
              76 80 45
              ...]
```

From here it is trivial to select every third participant:

```
testScores(1:3:end, :)
```

and then to find the mean:

```
mean(testScores(1:3:end,:),2)
```

Comment: If this solves your problem please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)